# Why is a variable an int in one instance and a string in another depending on what I compare it to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

This code:

```
values = ("xdr_s1_18021664256", "xdr_s1_18021664257", "xdr_s1_18021664258","xdr_s1_18021664259")

list_of_strings = []
string_with_highest_number = ''
max_value = 0
print(type(max_value))
for i in values:
    x = i.split("_")[-1] 
    if x > max_value:
        max_value = i
        string_with_highest_number = i
print(string_with_highest_number)
```

Yields this error:

```
<class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_delete.py", line 9, in <module>
    if x > max_value:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

**x** is a string and **max_value** integer. I cannot compare these two. Makes sense. So, I change the type of x to integer. So, the code looks like this:

```
values = ("xdr_s1_18021664256", "xdr_s1_18021664257", "xdr_s1_18021664258","xdr_s1_18021664259")

list_of_strings = []
string_with_highest_number = ''
max_value = 0
print(type(max_value))
for i in values:
    x = i.split("_")[-1] 
    if int(x) > max_value:
        max_value = i
        string_with_highest_number = i
print(string_with_highest_number)
```

And, to my surprise, this time it yields this error:

```
<class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_delete.py", line 9, in <module>
    if int(x) > max_value:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

So, when I check the type of **max_value** before the loop, it is an integer. But then I get an error saying max_value is a string!

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: It reproduces just fine. I can copy the block of copy, `%paste` it into iPython with CPython 3.6, and I get the exact same output as the OP.

Comment: You missed the cast to int while storing it in max_value

Comment: Initially, your code failed at the first iteration.  Now it fails at the second iteration, after you bind max_value to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After printing the type of `max_value`, you then reassign it to something different:

```
max_value = i
```

Since `i` names a string, `max_value` now names that same string. So, next time through the loop, when you do this:

```
if int(x) > max_value:
```

… it fails, because `max_value` is a string.

---

What you *probably* wanted to do was convert the value to an `int` before storing it, just as you convert the other value to an `int` before comparing:

```
if int(x) > max_value:
    max_value = int(i)
```

---

You may be confused because you're thinking in terms of something more like C++.

In C++, a variable is a typed slot where values live. When you assign to a variable, you're casting the value to that type and then copying it into the slot in memory. None of that is true in Python.

In Python, variables aren't slots in memory, they're just names for values that live wherever they want to live. When you assign to a variable, you're just making the variable another name for that value. There's no automatic casting like in C++. And there's no types for variables—any variable can hold any value.

It is often confusing to assign values of unrelated types to the same variable at different times. You can use a static type checker like Mypy, or a linter, or another kind of static analyzer to point out the potential confusion, if you find yourself doing this often.

---

You may also be confused because you're thinking of something more like Scheme. In Scheme, variables are just names for values, but you usually don't rebind them. You *can*, but more commonly you shadow them with a more local binding, and the binding is still there, hiding further up the stack. I don't think this is your issue here, so I won't explain further.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to find the max by passing a `lambda` function as the `key` to `max()`:

```
max(values, key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[-1]))
#'xdr_s1_18021664259'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = ("xdr_s1_18021664256", "xdr_s1_18021664257", "xdr_s1_18021664258","xdr_s1_18021664259")

list_of_strings = []
string_with_highest_number = ''
max_value = 0
print(type(max_value))
for i in values:
    x = i.split("_")[-1] 
    if int(x) > max_value:
        max_value = i // problem occurs here
        string_with_highest_number = i
print(string_with_highest_number)
```

Your problem is occuring when you assign `i` to `max_value`. After the first time it is run `max_value` receives the value `"xdr_s1_18021664256"` which is a string. You should assign max value to `int(x)`.